# Placeholder text in QML TextEdit

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I am looking for a way to show a text hint stating the expected input as advice for the user. Take the Google search bar for example:

[image]

Is there a property I am missing, or is this something that has to be achieved through scripting?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The property doesn't exist on the Qt Quick input items. You can vote for the feature [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56153).

In the meantime, you can use [`TextArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html#details) from Qt Quick Controls 2.

If you would rather use pure Qt Quick, you can do something similar to what the Controls do and add a `Text` item above the field:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit
        width: 200
        height: 50

        property string placeholderText: "Enter text here..."

        Text {
            text: textEdit.placeholderText
            color: "#aaa"
            visible: !textEdit.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`TextField`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.htm) from Qt Quick Controls  1 also does that.

Answer (score 5):

This is kinda old but I found another necessity for **Android builds**.
Since Android only send the text editing signal after you press ok in virtual keyboard, the placeholder remains there. So to avoid it, I recommend:

```
TextEdit {
    id: textEdit
    width: 200
    height: 50

    property string placeholderText: "Enter text here..."

    Text {
        text: textEdit.placeholderText
        color: "#aaa"
        visible: !textEdit.text && !textEdit.activeFocus // <----------- ;-)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want one line input then why not use [TextField](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html) ?